# why SetWorldTransform fails when drawrectangle with graphics first and drawtext with cdc second

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi+

I draw a rectangle and text with `Graphics` and `CDC` respectively.

```
CDC dcMem;
dcMem.SetWorldTransform(&xform);  //magnify by x2.0
Graphics myg(dcMem);
myg.DrawRectangle(&mypen, 10, 10, 100, 100);   //1
dcMem.DrawText(mystring, 1, &ss, 
       DT_WORDBREAK | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_LEFT | DT_NOPREFIX);  //2
```

`DrawText()` fails to magnify.

If reverse the order of 1 and 2 it works well.

Why?

Comment: At a guess I'd say Gdiplus resets the transform on the DC you give it. Probably if you use `myg.SetTransform()` it would work.

Comment: Above code will not draw anything on the screen. `dcMem.DrawText` is only drawing to memory dc. You must have something like `Graphics gdc(dc);` where `dc` is the screen dc, and then you draw the memory dc on to screen dc.

Comment: I omitted the details.

Comment: solved.  redesignate the transform.

Comment: @mathddsccc you should answer your own question and tell us more about the solution you found.